# Send custom message in express.js error handling middleware

Tags: node.js, rest, express, single-page-application

I have a REST API built with express.js and an SPA, which are communicating with each other. I have my error handling middleware as explained [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers). I get the correct error code on the frontend, but the message is always `Request failed with error code ...` How can I send custom messages via either `res.status(4xx).json({message: 'My custom message to show on the SPA'})` or `res.status(4xx).send('My custom message to show on the SPA')`? Since I'm not rendering anything from the server, I can't add the message directly in my DOM. I have to send a json or text response.

Comment: Yes, you do have to send the data in json format and tackle it in DOM to showcase the custom error message

Comment: Okay, I found out that on the frontend, we were using axios and axios just puts the message in it's own object: ```error.response?.data?.message```. The message property on the error object doesn't contain the message sent by the server.

Comment: `res.status(4xx).json({message: 'My custom message to show on the SPA'})` If you are referring to this line and anticipating the error message it should be just `message` in the frontend. Not  `error.response?.data?.message`

Comment: Yes, with a normal fetch request, that is the case, but we were using axios on the FE. Axios adds its own functions on that response.